# Enviar Gson (JSON) mediante HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, json, gson

Estoy intentando enviar los datos en **JSON** desde android (cliente) a un servidor PHP que únicamente guardará estos datos en la BD y enviará un 1 o un 0 dependiendo del éxito o fracaso de la operacion INSERT.

He leido que hay una librería llamada **Gson** para parsear objetos java a JSON. He buscado código sobre esta librería y he encontrado que la forma de pasear el objeto sería así: **(MAL)**

```
*Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(bollo, Pan.class); /*bollo es un objeto ya instaciado de la clase Pan*/*
```

El parseo a JSON está mal, según https://www.programacion.com.py/moviles/android/gson-libreria-para-parsear-json-en-android sería: **(BIEN)**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(bollo);
```

Pero no estoy muy seguro de que eso esté del todo correcto.

Aprovecho para poner mi clase **Pan.java**:

```
public class Pan {

    String precio;
    String cereal;
    String semilla;
    String nombre;
    String coccion;
}
```

Tambien tengo implementados los métodos setter y getter de cada una de las variables pero de momento los omito por no poner mucho código.

Por otro lado he buscado un ejemplo de envio de una peticion POST con **HttpURLConnection**, totalmente desconocido para mi porque yo utilizaba la libería de apache, obsoleta ya desde hace algunas versiones, y he eocntrado esto, pero es un código que no entiendo y que veo que le falta donde poner el String que contiene el JSON y la url de mi servidor.

```
 public static String makeRequest(String uri, String json) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        String url;
        String data = json;
        String result = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String line = null; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        return result;
    }
```

Mis pregunas son:

- ¿Está bien parseado el objeto pan a JSON mediante el uso de Gson? **Estaba mal**, dejo el fallo
- **¿Cómo envío esta cadena en JSON a traves de  HttpURLConnection?**

Muchas gracias, se que está muy verde el código, pero no encuentro nada y estoy un poco desquiciado.

Un saludo.

Comment: Probaste el código? Hay algo que no funcione?

Comment: @Juan, no el problema de ese código es que no viene un ningun lado la url del servidor ni donde va la cadena JSON, es un ejemplo que he visto en un foro ingleés pero que no sé ni por dónde cogerlo. Sabes de algun tutorial de HttpURLConecction?

Comment: No entiendo. El metodo tiene dos parametros. La url se le pasa en el parametro uri, y el string json resultante del gson.toJson(...) como parametro json.

Comment: @Juan, entonces terndria que hacer la llamada : String resultado = makeRequest(www.servidor.es,  json) y en el String resultado me devolvería la respuesta del servidor? Esa era mi duda, hacer la llamada, lo que pasa que debería hacerla medainte un AsynTask no?

Comment: Sí, la url entre comillas porque es un string, y json siendo la variable que tiene el resultado de gson.toJson(...)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, una ultima duda ... la variable String json puede no serlo? es decir puede ser un String nromal? Otra cosa, da como comentario de respuesta si quieres la llamada y asi lo marcamos como solucionado

Comment: @user2070274 ya tienes los problemas resueltos?

Comment: @David creo que sí, mañana o pasado probaré, lo de parsear el objeto a JSON usando Gson ya lo he visto más veces así asi que supongo que está bien, además nadie ha comentado nada, y parece que la funcion que usa HttpURLConnect también es correcta, sólo me faltaba la llamada